# How to read recursion methods accurately

Tags: java, recursion, calculator

I'm preparing for a java programming exam that's coming up in a few days and I've been tryna get my head around this:

`The initial starting value of int num is 8`

```
public int func1(int num)
{
    if(num <=1) return 1;
    return num + func1 (num - 3);
}
```

How do you go through through the `return num + func1 (num - 3)` part? 
I don't get how that line of code works

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you understand recursion.

```
return 8 + func1(5)
return 8 + 5 + func1(2)
return 8 + 5 + 2 + func1(-1)
return 8 + 5 + 2 + 1
```

and finally returns like

```
return 8 + 5 + 3
return 8 + 8
return 16
```

Comment: I thought so... I talked with a few peers and their answers were -1. I am not quite sure why

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to understand recursion is

Assume that the whole `public int func1(int num)` is inserted in the return

so ur function returns somewhat in this way

```
return 8 +         func1((8) - 3) // i.e return 8 + func1(5)
return 8 + 5 +     func1((5) - 3) // i.e return 8 + 5 + func1(2)
return 8 + 5 + 2 + func1((2) - 3) // i.e return 8 + 5 + 2 + func1(-1)
return 8 + 5 + 2 + 1
```

So total will be 16

Answer (score 0):

Just trace through it the exact same as for any other method call. It's just calling itself which is another way to do a loop.

i.e.

```
func1(8)
    calls func1(8-3)
         calls func1(5-3)
             calls func1(2-3)
                 returns 1 as -1 < 1
             returns 2+1
         returns 5+3
    returns 8+8
```

So the final result is 16.

Comment: I thought so... I talked with a few peers and their answers were -1. I am not quite sure why

Answer (score 0):

"The only way to understand recursion is to understand recursion".

Now seriously, you need to think of the execution of a recursive program as a stack with a basic case and a general case:

For instance the factorial method:

> Basic case: f(n) = 1, if n = 0.
>
> General case: f(n) = n*f(n-1), otherwise.

Result would be:

```
f(n) = n*f(n-1)
f(n-1) = (n-1)*f(n-2) 
...
f(2) = 2*f(1)
f(1) = 1*f(0)
f(0) = 1
```

Basically you need to go down until the basic case and then reconstruc the result via the partial results you are finding.

Recursive algorithms are very useful for some methods which otherwise would require lots of memory to store intermediates value.